# Binding a control to a member of a collection from an OData model

Tags: sapui5

I have setup an oData service that returns the tags of an entity in a collection of Strings. If you look at the metadata.xml, you'll see something like this:

```
<Property Name="Tags" Type="Collection(Edm.String)"/>
```

A typical entity would like like this:

```
{
    "Id": 120983,
    "Title": "Title of something awesome!",
    "Tags": [ "Tag1", "Tag2" ]
}
```

I was hoping to use sap.m.Tokenizer and sap.m.Token to display the tag-list as a set of tokens. To do so, I have included the section below to my xml view:

```
<core:Title text="Tags" />
<Tokenizer tokens="{Tags}">
    <Token text="tag" editable="false" />
</Tokenizer>
```

It now shows a list of tags, like so:

[image]

The next step is to replace the hardcoded token text with the strings from the tag collection. I am wondering how I should do this though. The strings in that array don't have a name, so something like text="{Name}" won't do the job. Something like text="{}" also doesn't work of course.

Is there any way I can bind the text property of a sap.m.Token control to the strings in my collection?

Comment: I just read the last paragraph (after posting my answer). Seems like `text="{}"` does work, or did I just misunderstand something?

Comment: Hi Marc, the funny thing is that it does work if you're using a JSONModel (as shown in the jsbin). I can't get it to work with an ODataModel though. I'm trying to get a jsbin together for that as well, but it's slightly challenging, because it requires a service call to be made (CORS etc). Will get on this tomorrow.

Comment: Since OData is basically JSON I am optimistic ;) Concerning CORS.. try prefixing your URL with this neat CORS app, e. g.: `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://myservice.com/path/to/service`

Comment: I'm running into quite some issues building an actual service that supports a collection of strings, that connects decently to OpenUI5 (dataservice version etc). I think I'll just have to give this a pass as it's too time-consuming, and can't justify spending that much time into solving a relatively small issue. I do appreciate all the effort your guys have made into helping me out. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

It's perfectly possible with your current data structure.

How about the following: http://jsbin.com/yisumilana/1/edit?html,output

```
<Tokenizer tokens="{path: '/Tags'}">
    <Token text="{}" editable="false" />
</Tokenizer>
```

Since `/Tags` is a good ol' array of strings, you can use the tag "as is", i. e. you don't need provide a path.

---

Credit to @[keshet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3649862/keshet) for providing the JSBin example.

Comment: An ODataModel doesn't seem to work the JSONModel works. Nevertheless, I really appreciate the effort of creating a jsbin for me, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem recently, sap.m.MultiComboBox has the property

```
selectedKeys : {type : "string[]", group : "Data", defaultValue : []}
```

the selected key are rendered as Tokens, I couldn't see a way to make Type="Collection(Edm.String)" work in ABAP

the solution we came up with was to use a function which parsed the tokens from a string

```
parseStringArray: function(sArray) {
    return sArray ? sArray.split(",") : [];
},
```

in action

```
new MultiComboBox({
    selectedKeys: {
        path: "Tags",
        formatter: this.parseStringArray
    }
})
```

Comment: That's a very interesting approach. I've played around with the MultiComboBox and this indeed seems to work for the selectedKeys. I'm was trying to do the same thing for the Tokenizer though, but am still having a tough time there. Would have hoped something like this would have worked: 
     <Tokenizer tokens="{
       path: 'Tags',
       formatter: '.formatter.parseStringArray'
      }">
      <Token text="{}" editable="false" />
     </Tokenizer>